# Where would a wildcard DNS record be prioritized?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a DNS setup going on where I have several subdomains that cname out to google apps, but I was wondering if I could wildcard the rest of my subdomains, and have my google apps cname correctly. In other words, would the records that aren't a wildcards be parsed before the wildcard record?

Answer (score 1):

As per [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) sections [4.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-4.3.2) and [4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-4.3.3), a wildcard record is always of least priority. Any existing resource records in the same zone are preferred.

[RFC 4592](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4592) might also be an interesting read for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check and see if your DNS host currently supports wildcard subdomains, and if they do, there should be no problems as existing records will be prioritized.